# Firebase Auth REST API - Adding more fields to Sign up

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add more fields to accounts:signUp  e.i
*fields needed: firstname surname phone...*
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-create-email-password

so far I can pass the email and password and a user will be created, how do I add more fields? and store that information in a **users** collection in cloudfirestore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Auth does not have a facility for storing arbitrary user data along with an account.  You're supposed to use a database to store that, and link the record you store there to the user ID that Firebase Auth assigns to the user.

Comment: alright, I wasn't aware of that, thanks! if that is the case, can I , soon after the user been successfully registered store the additional information in a different table in firebase?

Comment: I've found more documentation that confirms what I just asked https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-link-with-email-password